# visual studio 2012 not supporte database helper namespace in c#

Tags: c#

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbDKg.png]

When I use database helper in default.aspx in visual studio whose screenshot I have given
Please see and tell what I do if any other solution

Comment: Check if your project has reference to that required library in solution explorer -> references

Comment: Look at the warning; change your target framework.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the warning, it's because your application only targets `.NET Framework 4.5`, but the `Database_Helper` requires `4.5.2` and above.

The solution is to change your targeted `.NET Framework` to `4.5.2` or higher.

Hope it helps!